# How to check if symbol is global via Typescript compiler API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

*referring to symbols in the TS typechecker, not ES6 Symbols*

Given an identifier node in the TypeScript AST, I can do `typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(identNode)`.  How do I check if that symbol is declared in the global scope as opposed to an external module?

I'm writing a language service plugin that must show a warning every time certain functions refer to externally-declared values.  They're allowed to refer to locally-declared variables and to globals, but nothing from external modules.

I'm not sure if I need to use `getDeclarations()` or not.  I feel like this sort of info might be encoded within `ts.SymbolFlags` but I can't figure out all the flags.  For example, what does the `Transient` flag mean?

Comment: Did you ever work out how to do this?

Comment: The closest I came is detailed in my comment below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574131/how-to-check-if-symbol-is-global-via-typescript-compiler-api?noredirect=1#comment88185333_50575891

Answer (score 0):

A global symbol will have an `undefined` `.parent`.

Whether or not a symbol is Transient is an implementation detail you shouldn't need to worry about

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I'm seeing something different from the compiler.  Symbols declared within `declare global {}` appear to have a parent, but I can check if `parent.escapedName === 'global'`.  Interface `Symbols` doesn't have a `parent` property; is it safe to use it even though it's marked internal?  Finally, `const foo` within a function creates a symbol without a parent.  To differentiate from globals, should I check `getDeclarations()[0]` and see if it's within the function body?

Comment: I meant to say escapedName === global with two underscores; StackOverflow changed the formatting

Comment: This is simply incorrect... local variable symbols have undefined `.parent` as well. Besides, `.parent` is a internal property of symbols, so one should not count on it.

Answer (score 0):

`typeChecker.getFullyQualifiedName`

returns global.symbolName

```
/**
 * Test if a symbol is in the global scope
 * @param typeChecker - the typecheker
 * @param symbol - the symbol
 * @returns true when the symbol is in the global scope
 */
function isGlobalSymbol(typeChecker: ts.TypeChecker, symbol: ts.Symbol): boolean {
    // get the name
    const name = typeChecker.getFullyQualifiedName(symbol);
    // get the position of the first dot
    const dotPosition = name.indexOf(".");
    if (dotPosition !== -1) {
        // there should not be a second dot after the first dot
        const nextDotPosition = name.indexOf(".", dotPosition + 1);
        // the first part of the name should be global
        if (nextDotPosition === -1 && name.substring(0, dotPosition) === "global") {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```